# Is there a way to convert a number range into numbers? In my example "1-100" into numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel

I need to exclude certain postalcodes, but a lot of codes are written as "300-302" or "100-399" (there are many more). I need them as seperate numbers, so "300-302" as 300 301 302. Manually writing them down would take too much time. Is there a way in Excel to do this automatically or maybe a tool online (so far I haven't found any)?

Right now, I'm using these numbers in a different way than how I want them to use. But basically it is a huge sql query with BETWEEN(300-302) OR BETWEE(100-399) OR etc.

Comment: Search for `-` and replace with a space?

Comment: You could use a macro, vba to generate the numbers in the range

Comment: Or textsplit and sequence if you have Excel 365

Comment: Or, using `TEXTBEFORE()` & `TEXTAFTER()` with `SEQUENCE()` ==> `=SEQUENCE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"-")-TEXTBEFORE(A1,"-")+1,,TEXTBEFORE(A1,"-"))`